# org.hibernate.HibernateException:No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to call next statement:

```
public List<User> getList(int master_id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
            List<User> result = (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createQuery("from User WHERE master_id=:master_id")
                    .setInteger("master_id", master_id).list();
            return result;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

But then I catch

> No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow
>   creation of non-transactional one here

Someone says I have to add a `@Transactional` annotation to this, but as you can see there is no need to do that, because it's `SELECT` query. What do?

hibernate.cfg:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.smsc.domain.User" />   
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.smsc.domain.UserRoles" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.smsc.domain.WhiteList" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.smsc.domain.BlackList" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.smsc.domain.Distribution" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.smsc.domain.Range" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.smsc.domain.SmsEntity" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.smsc.domain.Archive" />
        <mapping class="ru.tenet.smsc.domain.Priority" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

SessionFactory:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/db/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Can you paste sources for: hibernate.cfg and sessionFactory?

Answer (score 0):

**@Transactional** is not only for insert/updates, is also for SELECTs. You can see this because one of the parameters of the annotation can be **readOnly=true** (this means your transaction is not going to commit anything)

Answer (score 0):

You must bind the current session to the current thread

```
Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, true);
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, 
new SessionHolder(session));
try {
 do your work ...
}
finally {
  TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(sessionFactory);
  SessionFactoryUtils.closeSessionIfNecessary(session, sessionFactory);
}
```

If you have a webapp, then you should add the Spring [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](http://springtips.blogspot.com/2007/07/open-session-in-view.html) filter